# fetching field values from the LOG file and writing its value to a new .txt file in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, vim

I have this data in my input file. I am working on writing a script to fetch values of the particular fields from the below log file

```
2020-12-21 18:28:32,904 REQID:100|REGREQ:SIADR:APIID:10|APPCTX:1720|FROM:<ip:919876543210@abc.idea.com>;tag=N8Fabcdc5r|EXPIRE:Expires:600000|CSEQ:123|TAGREQ:METHOD_NAME:REGISTER|ARG:OPT:1|OPTS:ISDN:|LEN:12|VAL:919876543211

2020-12-21 18:28:32,904 REQID:100|REGRES:SIADR:APIID:11|APPCTX:1720|STATUS:200

there may be so many rows in the file , what I want to check is process each row, check whether that row has field [REGREQ:SIADR:APIID:] if its there in the row then access the value for the field:--> REGREQ:SIADR:APIID:1  , if the value is 1, then
1. read the value of FROM field -> need to fetch only --> ip:919876543210@abc.idea.com
2. read the value present in the field VAL ---> 919876543211
if APIID: value is other than 1 skip the row
```

below is sample code I wrote but not getting how to acces field value in the row

```
`cat $SOURCE_PATH/input.log | grep -v Orig |awk
        BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," }
        {
        
        } >> output_file.txt`
```

I want to parse the file fetch the values for those fields and write into a .txt file as comma seperated
help me how can I  fetch the field values in shell script, I tried by splitting by pipe then accessing via the position but it can get changed in future new fields gets added in between

```
Sample output file:
2020-12-21 18:28:32,ip:919876543210@abc.idea.com,919876543211,true
```

last value is true, how I found is in second entry in input file for the reqID:100 , ifthe APIID is 11 I have to fetch the value of STATUS field i.e 200, if it is 200 I have to write as true else false.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question, could you please post sample of expected output too in your question for better understanding of it, thank you.

Comment: hi sir , I have updated my question, Can you please help me with the better approach for solving this problem, I have multiple rows in my log file for every reqID there are 2 entries first one is the request and second is the response row. the value of first request is success or not that i can get in second entry with API ID 11, so I have to check for 2 rows and prepare a final file there it show the reqid with number and also whether it is success or not as I shown in the sample output

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with awk:

```
awk -F\| '$2 ~ /REGREQ/ { 
                          delete map; # Clear arrays
                          delete map1;
                          delete map2;
                          split($2,map,":"); # Check that the second | delimited field contains REGREQ and then split the second field into the array map using ":" as the delimiter
                          if (map[4]==1) { # If the fourth index of the array map is 1, process
                            addr=gensub(/(^.*:<)(ip:.*)(>.*$)/,"\\2",$4); # Create a variable addr with just the ip address using gensub
                            split($1,map2,",");split($NF,map1,":"); # Split the first field using comma as the delimiter
                           }  
                         }
$2 ~ /REGRES/ && map2[1] { split($1,map3,":"); # Process the REGRES lines only when map2[1] is set. Get the REQID value in array map3
                           split($NF,map4,":"); # Get the status code in array map4
                           if (map3[4]==100 && map4[2]=="200") { # Set statis variable to true if status code is 200 and REQID is 100
                              statis="true" 
                           } 
                           else { 
                              statis="false" 
                           };
                           printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",map2[1],addr,map1[2],statis # Print the data we need
                         }' file
```

One liner:

```
awk -F\| '$2 ~ /REGREQ/ { delete map;delete map1;delete map2;split($2,map,":");if (map[4]==10) { addr=gensub(/(^.*:<)(ip:.*)(>.*$)/,"\\2",$4);split($1,map2,",");split($NF,map1,":") } } $2 ~ /REGRES/ && map2[1] { split($1,map3,":");split($NF,map4,":");if (map3[4]==100 && map4[2]=="200") { statis="true" } else { statis="false" };printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",map2[1],addr,map1[2],statis}' file
```